# Special characters in Sikuli script

Tags: special-characters, sikuli

I am trying to use some French special characters with Sikuli, when I type this in the Sikuli IDE,

```
App.open('C:\\à table\\app.exe')
```

But I get this error :

```
[log] App.open C:\Ã  table\NDC.exe(0)
[error] App.open failed: C:\Ã  table\NDC.exe not found
```

It seems that Sikuli doesn't handle utf-8 properly for the moment. All I could find in Google was the same problem with type() function and to use paste() instead, which uses the clipboard.

Is there a workaround in the case of App.open ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Could make a bat file, and have `App.Open('path/to/bat/file.bat')` which inside contains the path to the .exe

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this problem seems that Python 2.5.X doesn't support character encodings properly. One has to use tricks like encode('cp1252'), encode('utf8')...

Since Sikuli is based on Jython which is based on Python 2.5.2, we are stuck!

I wished I lived in a country only using the standard ASCII table, I really hate all these problems related to codepage and encodings.